# Set the PYTHONPATH for a older version of Python to a directory where I want to install it though I have a default version of Python3

Tags: python-3.x

I am using ubuntu 18.04. I have Python-3.6.6 installed as a default version. But for practice I have installed **Python-3.6.5** from source code to a directory where I wanted to install it and changed the *.bashrc* file accordingly. But it is showing me the default python3 path when I call "which" command.
   How to use the python version which one I have installed recently?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to run some practice scripts you can select directly which python you want to use for your script. In the command line, e.g. type

```
PYTHONPATH=/foo/bar/python365 python somescript.py
```

where `/foo/bar/python365` points to your `python-3.6.5`

You can also change your PYTHONPATH variable to look first in the `python-3.6.5` folder before it looks to the default python (3.6.6) you had installed before. However, I do not recommend this, since it will make all python applications choose the `python-3.6.5` as default. For extended practice with `python-3.6.5` consider a [virtual environment](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/) or an [anaconda environment](https://www.anaconda.com/).

Comment: But if I write PYTHONPATH=/foo/bar/python3.6.5 python3 --version, it is showing the default version of python. What should I do?

Comment: Do you have an alias in your `.bashrc` which selects for `python3` automatically the default python? What does PYTHONPATH=/foo/bar/python3.6.5 python --version` give as output (note `python` not `python3`

Answer (score 0):

You should use virtualenv or something similar, like pipenv, I myself use virtualenv.

Here's a guide on how to do that: https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/

virtualenv is a bit lower level and so not that intuitive to use, but since I used virtualenv before I found pipenv, I just stuck with it, while adding a few aliases to my `.bashrc` to make it easier.

I used two different python versions because discord.py would break on 3.7 (that doesn't seem to be the case anymore, but I still have it setup with 3.6 and 3.7), so here's what my .bashrc for two different versions looked like, this is on windows, but if you are on unix system or macOS (I want to make this answer as general as possible, it works the same on all operating systems really), just change the paths to lead to your interpreters (whichever you have) and don't use winpty:

```
alias python36="winpty C:/Users/Hevaesi/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/python.exe"
alias python37="winpty C:/Users/Hevaesi/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/python.exe"
alias pip36="C:/Users/Hevaesi/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/python.exe -m pip"
alias pip37="C:/Users/Hevaesi/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/python.exe -m pip"
alias venv36="python36 -m virtualenv"
alias venv37="python37 -m virtualenv"
alias python="winpty python"
```

Now, to use Python 3.6, I use `venv36 venv` in my project folder, and it setups Python 3.6 environment, using `venv37 venv` would create Python 3.7 environment.

I also wrote a function to make activating less of a hassle (again, this is in bashrc)

```
activate() {
    if [ "$#" == 1 ]; then
        source "$1/Scripts/activate"
    else
        echo "Usage: activate <env_name>"
    fi
}
```

So, after I created my env once, I go to project folder, type `activate venv` and it starts up whatever version I wanted the project to have all by itself, to run my project I just use `python myfile.py`, when virtual environment is activated, it will use the interpreter that's in active virtual environment, regardless of what you have in your PATH variable. Also, using `pip` will automatically install to your virtual environment, not your actual installation, meaning global package list will be clean, or in best case, completely empty.

You should only install what you need and keep it separate environments, normally you use a single environment per project. Well, unless your project is client/server at once (for whatever reason) and server uses different libraries than client, for example, more of them, client environment could have less modules since that's what the server is for, to provide something without having to do it yourself, so they could be two projects in one, hence two different environments, separating dependencies based on what the "unit" in the project really needs.

Note: you have to install virtualenv (or pipenv or whatever you want to use really) into all of your python installations, if you want to create virtual environments from them, that's what pip36 and pip37 here is for - for installing packages directly into actual python installations, for now, I only had to do `pip36 install virtualenv` and `pip37 install virtualenv`.